# Subscript out of range - copy worksheet to new workbook Excel

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I'm attempting very simple process, where I am copying one worksheet to a new workbook as shown in the  following code:

```
Private Sub btn_Documents_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim printrange As Range
    Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook

    Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewWorkbook

    .Title = "Document Register"
    .SaveAs Filename:="some file path" & " Program documents status.xlsx"
End With
Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0.0").worksheets("Document Register").Copy Before:=NewWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Unload Me
frm_Control.Show

End Sub
```

This exact code has worked for me previously, however, this time it is throwing a subscript out of range error on the copy line of the code. I have double checked the file name, name of the sheet I am copying from, and it is all correct, so I am now at a loss as to why its is throwing this error.

Comment: Check your `Sheets name` on each workbook

Comment: What workbook is the sheet "Document Register"  in? The new one, or an existing one you're running this from?  I would also add the workbook name before `Sheets("Document Register")`

Comment: @0m3r - like I said in the question, all of the sheet names are correct

Comment: @BruceWayne - I have now added the name of the workbook I am copying the document register sheet from, and it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: Try the full workbook name (including the file extension)

Comment: You'll get the subscript out of range error if the sheet you're referring to does not exist. I know you said that the sheet names are correct, but did you verify that Sheet1 is in NewWorkbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply copy the worksheet directly to a new workbook (without manually creating the target workbook)?

```
Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0.0").worksheets("Document Register").Copy
with activeworkbook
     .Title = "Document Register"
     .SaveAs Filename:="some file path" & " Program documents statusx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
end with
```

Note that I am using the `FileFormat` parameter of .SaveAs and discarding the file extension from the filename.

If you need to use the `NewWorkbook` workbook object for something else than what you have shown, it is easy enough to set it to the activeworkbook you created on the copy-to-new-workbook-on-the-fly.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. However, I am copying the sheet to existing workbook. So, this solution doesn't work for me. All the sheets are present and named correctly. One observation that I will like to add is the sheet is copied in the target workbook and the code doesn't move forward and copy command is repeatedly called without any changes and then throws the error.